# Problem rendering SVG in opera using Raphael JS

Tags: css, svg, opera, visibility, raphael

I am trying to use Raphael JS to make some nice SVG graphics on a page. You can see my attempt here at http://www.thecultivation.co.uk . It seems to work on all browsers quite nicely except for opera 11. Most graphics work, but if you click on any of the menu options in opera, the next lot of graphics don't render.  Anyone have any idea why the svg graphics won't render?

When I do ctrl + shift + i in opera and bring up the dragonfly developer tools I can see the svg element, and when I click on the relevant svg path elements in dragonfly, it eventually becomes visible for some reason.. but not on normal loading.  I am using a lot of divs on top of each other and using css display:none/block and visibility:visible/hidden on some of the elements.

Anyone come up with similar problems?  I would love to hear..

Comment: Reported this as Opera bug CORE-39329.

Comment: nice one for this. what's the etiquette here.. anything else i need to do to thank you??

Answer (score 0):

Works for me today with Opera 11.11

Comment: nice one for this. what's the etiquette hear.. anything else i need to do to thank you??